How can I scroll down in a scrollable panel (not the whole window) with Selenium?
I was trying to scrape the pokemon names and usage data from the left-side panel in https://www.pikalytics.com/ . I tried with BeautifulSoup, but apparently it could only scrape the first 25 data as the source code was not fully stretched. As a result, I'd have to scroll down in the panel to have full access. But how?
Here the solutions I tried:
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.pikalytics.com')
panel = '//*[@id="mini_list_wrapper"]'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, panel).send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

and thus it returned an error of element not interactable. I have tried some other xpaths from its child nodes but none of them worked.

Check the working code below with explanation:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.pikalytics.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Below for loop will scroll down within the div element 10 times.
# Change the number of times to scroll by changing the range
for i in range(10):
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pokedex-wrapper-min")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", element)
    time.sleep(2)

time.sleep(10)


You can use API request
import requests

url = 'https://www.pikalytics.com/api/l/2024-06/gen9vgc2024regg-1760'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

print(data)

Or scroll with selenium
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains, ScrollOrigin


with webdriver.Chrome() as browser:
    browser.get("https://www.pikalytics.com/")
    time.sleep(1)
    actions = ActionChains(browser)
    #find the element that we want to scroll
    scroll_obj = browser.find_element(By.ID, "pokedex_wrapper")
    #ready object for scrolling
    rdy_for_scroll = ScrollOrigin.from_element(scroll_obj)
    flag = 0
    #getting information about the length of the object
    scroll_obj_height = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollHeight', scroll_obj)

    #scrolling until we get to the end
    while flag != scroll_obj_height:
        #scroll element
        actions.scroll_from_origin(rdy_for_scroll, 0, 20000).perform()
        #uploading data
        time.sleep(1)
        #update flag
        flag = scroll_obj_height
        #updating the length of the object
        scroll_obj_height = browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollHeight', scroll_obj)


You can get all the data from the API using requests:
import requests

url = 'https://www.pikalytics.com/api/l/2024-06/gen9vgc2024regg-1760'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

print(f'{len(data) = }')


As for scrolling with selenium, you need to make sure you are selecting the correct (scrollable) element:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.pikalytics.com/'
driver.get(url)

wrapper = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'pokedex_wrapper'))) 

while driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].clientHeight + arguments[0].scrollTop !== arguments[0].scrollHeight', wrapper):
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight)', wrapper)
    time.sleep(1)
    wrapper = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pokedex_wrapper')


data = wrapper.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul#min_list > a')
print(f'{len(data) = }')
driver.quit()

